# Command Line Git working but VS 2017 giving 403 error?

Tags: git, visual-studio, command-line, azure-devops

I am facing a strange problem that I cannot seem to find a solution for. The problem started when our TFS was upgraded and the url's changed. So I have changed the URL's for the repository in my projects.

However I cannot fetch\pull from the Team Explorer. If I run `fetch` it does nothing for a while and then returns the following error in Output:

```
Error encountered while fetching: Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access '*******': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

The requested url is correct as you will see below.

If I go to the solution folder in the Command Line and run `git fetch` and then `git pull` everything works just fine and the solution is updated with the latest changes.

I have tried a whole lot of different things but is there something that I am missing that could cause this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I made sure that my credentials were updated under any saved credentials that might be being used. I tried re-cloning the solution which also did not work. I made sure that I had been added as someone who can pull from the solution.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of vs2017 installed?  The latest version of the Git Credential Manager?

Comment: @Matt I have the latest version of vs2017 and version 1.18.4 of GCM. Latest version of GCM is 1.18.5.